# How do you use media queries in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a carousel that uses javascript. 
For the desktop version, it shows 3 posts in the slider. 
However, I would like to put a media query on the slider so that it only displays one post at a time for the mobile version because the screen is smaller.

I found this:

```
<script>
function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  } else {
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
  }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
</script>

But I want to use this in there:

$('.post-wrapper').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  nextArrow: $('.next'),
  prevArrow: $('.prev'),

});
```

Instead of changing the background colours. How do I add mine to it?

Thank you in advance for your answers :)

Answer (score 3):

If Using slick carousel  just go through API reference first 
https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/api/

Answer (score 1):

Just create your media queries with css, and then append the classes you want when a condition is met in your JS.

Comment: I don't know how to do this. I can use media queries in css, but I don't know how to append the classes from my javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  var slides = x.matches ? 1 : 3;
  $('.post-wrapper').slick('slickSetOption', 'slidesToShow', slides, true);
}

$('.post-wrapper').slick({
  // .. set the initial values
});

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)");
myFunction(x);
x.addListener(myFunction);
```

You can use `slickSetOption` to dynamically edit the carousel.

Comment: Do I write it like this? 

```
<script>

function myFunction(x) {
  let slides = x.matches ? 1 : 3;
  $(element).slick('slickSetOption', 'slidesToShow', slides, true);
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction)




</script>```